# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'TP' was corrupted

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to do a pascal triangle but for some reason i have the error "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'TP' was corrupted." Can someone help me, please?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
int TP[100][100] = { 0 }, n;
do
{
    cout << "Digite a ordem do triangulo de pascal: ";
    cin >> n;
} while (n < 0 || n > 100);
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    TP[j][0] = 1;
    TP[j][j] = 1;
}
for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; TP[i][j] != 1; j++)
        TP[i][j] = TP[i - 1][j - 1] + TP[i - 1][j];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j != i + 1; j++)
        cout << TP[i][j] << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go beyond the array boundaries in `for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++)` for `i == n` when `n=100`.